# CakePHP not reading URL parameters correctly

Tags: url, cakephp, parameters

I have a link on a view like this

```
<a href="playlists/add?video[]=0&amp;video[]=4&amp;video[]=1" id="save_playlist">Save Playlist</a>
```

However, when it is clicked I am redirected to

```
/playlists/add/video[]=0&video[]=4&video[]=1
```

and the output of $this->params['url'] is

```
Array ( [url] => playlists/add/video[]=0 [video] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 1 ) )
```

instead of

`Array ( [url] => playlists/add/ [video] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 4 [2] => 1 ) )`

I can't work out why the firs parameter is always read as part of the url, nor why the leading ? is removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `playlists/add?video` -> `playlists/add/?video`

Or just write properly formatted URLs like

```
$this->Html->link('Save Playlist', array('controller' => 'playlists', 'action' => 'add', 'values[0]'=>3, 'values[1]'=>2, 'values[2]'=>23)); ?>
```

Comment: The variables are appended to the href by javascript so it's not making a difference how the URL is formatted initially. Changing playlists/add?video -> playlists/add/?video isn't helping either, Cake still removes the question mark